# PostgreSQL inserts question marks instead of unicode characters

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, unicode

Whenever an insertion occurs through my application, all Unicode characters (be it Japanese, Greek etc.) are replaced by question marks.

```
SAVEPOINT "DAO"
LOG:  execute <unnamed>: insert into foo values ($1,$2,$3)
DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '23', $2 = '34bcb5f2-e7ee-40cf-9103-f2d1bf2ac7acd853d7c6-1703-44d2-aa99-6fd1df84da37', $3 = 'Anyone-日本語_l'
```

As you can see from the above log entry, the database accepts the correct Unicode parameters.

However, after the insertion, the table entry looks like this:

```
23 | 34bcb5f2-e7ee-40cf-9103-f2d1bf2ac7acd853d7c6-1703-44d2-aa99-6fd1df84da37 | Anyone-???_l
```

My first guess was that this was a database configuration issue, however I have confirmed (to the best of my knowledge) that Postgres is indeed accepting UTF-8 by performing the following:

```
SHOW server_encoding;
server_encoding
-----------------
UTF8
(1 row)

SHOW client_encoding;
client_encoding
-----------------
UTF8
(1 row)
```

I have also further cornfirmed this by manually inserting an entry to the database:

```
INSERT INTO foo values(25, ‘the_id’, ‘ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘ’);
INSERT 0 1
25 | the_id | ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘ
```

As you can understand from the above, the database has accepted my values and has succesfully added the Unicode characters to the database.

At this point, I believe that the problem occurs when these values are pushed from my application to the JDBC connector and into the database. I thought that perhaps the JDBC connector needs to be told it will be transfering Unicode data. There is indeed a way to do this, by appending the following in the JDBC connector's URL:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost/bar?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Unfortunately, the above did not make any difference.

I have excluded the application's code as it is part of a very big project and the relevant pieces are fragmented here and there. However, I think that they are irrelevant to the problem as the Postgres log clearly displays the parameters received by it.

The query and the unicode data that is received by the database are correct so what is causing this problem?

```
OS: RHEL 6.6
Postgres version: 9.3.5
JDBC Connector: Tried a couple (8.1, 9.3)
JRE: 1.7
```

---

The database is indeed expecting UTF-8:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost --list

Name      |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
----------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------------
bar       | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

The *bytea* result of the relevant entry is the following:

```
SELECT foo_name::bytea FROM foo;

foo_name
--------------------------
\x416e796f6e652d3f3f3f5f6c
```

---

Question marks have actually been inserted into the database:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo_name LIKE 'Anyone-?%'
23 | 34bcb5f2-e7ee-40cf-9103-f2d1bf2ac7acd853d7c6-1703-44d2-aa99-6fd1df84da37 | Anyone-???_l
```

I have also grabbed the byte sequence of one of my tests that was generated by the JDBC controller before it was fed to the [PGStream](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/core/PGStream.html).

```
{65, 110, 121, 111, 110, 101, 45, -26, -105, -91, -26, -100, -84, -24, -86, -98, 95, 105}
```

I have converted this to a UTF-8 String by performing the following (in a stand-alone application):

```
String result = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The result was the correct one: *Anyone-日本語_i*

Comment: Just for the record, the `useUnicode=yes` and `characterEncoding=UTF-8` connection parameters do not apply to all JDBC drivers. They are specific to MySQL Connector/J, and they do not appear in the list of [connection parameters for the PostgreSQL JDBC Driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/93/connect.html#connection-parameters).

Comment: Try `psql -U postgres -h localhost --list` from an OS command line to list the databases and check the `Encoding` of the actual database in question. You have verified that the (default) encoding for the *server* is `UTF8` but it's possible that the *database* has a different encoding.

Comment: Run `select column_with_dubious_text::bytea from table` to know whether the actual bytes are the expected utf-8 representation. Depending on that you'll know if the problem is pre-insert or post-insert.

Comment: A question mark comes from a conversion to a non-Unicode encoding of a non-mappable code point. So if you have the data in a java variable, best dump the code points or bytes to see whether the data has a question mark (?=0x3F=63) or the outputing failed. Also you did not ensure all of us that into the database `?` was inserted. **A SELECT LIKE 'Anyone-?%' and 'Anyone-%'** will show that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After investigating deep down the legacy code I found and fixed the issue.

The database layer worked just fine; the problem occured when the system attempted to re-insert the same value into the database by using a [ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).

The ByteArrayInputStream was being populated by performing a [getBytes()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) in the String that contained the *foo_name*. However, UTF-8 encoding should be defined when calling this method.

By changing:

```
String name = "日本語";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(name.getBytes());
```

to:

```
String name = "日本語";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(name.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem with unicode-8, with postgres and glassfish. I tried this in the persistence.xml and it fixed. I hope that it can help you

```
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
           value="jdbc:postgresql://(url_Project)?useUnicode=yes"/>
</properties>
```

(url_Proyecto) is the complete url of the data base